# How to run tests from outside folder?

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have a directory like this:

```
home
  -node_modules
    --nightwatch
  -nwTests
    --example.js
```

and I try to run example.js as a nightwatch test with following command:

```
nightwatch -t ./../../nwTests/example.js
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Cannot find module '/home/node_modules/nightwatch/home/nwTests/example.
```

It works perfect when it is in the nightwatch folder, but I have to put the tests to outside. So, how can I run test from the outside? Thanks any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which OS you are on...

on mac or linux write a bash script to change to the right directory before running the file.

When the script ends you will still be in the directory where you started.

Create a file and add:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /full/path/to/nightwatch/folder

nightwatch -t example.js
```

then run chmod a+x filename to make the file executable.

Run it with ./filename.